# Ubuntu 22.10 RDP connection issues

Tags: networking, ssh, 22.10, rdp, remmina

I decided to set up a media box with Ubuntu 22.10, which I'm aware now uses Wayland by default. I am used to using VNC on X11, so haven't got much experience in the Wayland space or using RDP.

I'm trying to diagnose an issue connecting to my Ubuntu 22.10 media box using RDP. I have set up RDP using the GUI check boxes in Settings app and was able to establish an RDP session yesterday and it worked great for the few hours I needed it, but when trying again today, it doesn't appear to want to work now.

Using my desktop (yoda.lan @ 10.1.1.2 using Arch Linux), connected through 2 Cisco routers I can see and ping my media box (threepio.lan @ 10.1.2.2 Ubuntu 22.10) no problem.

Doing a port scan of my media box from my desktop, I can see the open RDP port;

```
nc -vz 10.1.2.2 20-3400
threepio.lan [10.1.2.2] 22 (ssh) open
threepio.lan [10.1.2.2] 3389 (ms-wbt-server) open
```

So I can see ssh and RDP ports open, and I can successfully connect to SSH and login without a problem. I don't have a firewall active on either machine and the access lists are permissive on the routers for LAN IPs.

When I try to connect an RDP session to the Ubuntu 22.10 box using Remmina, I get a black screen for a second and it looks like it is connecting, but then it disappears and I am returned to the main window.

I get this from the debug log;

```
(DEBUG) - (rcw_map_event) - Mapping: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_map_event) - Calling plugin mapping function
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Opening connection
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Disable smooth scrolling is set to 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Adding GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Have SSH
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - RDP data path is /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Not using system proxy settings
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel init
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - SSH tunnel initialization…
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port (tunnel)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - server: 10.1.2.2, port: 3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - protocol_plugin_start_direct_tunnel() returned [10.1.2.2]:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel has been optionally initialized. Now connecting to 10.1.2.2:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - gfx_h264_available: 1
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set by the user: 804x1348
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set after workarounds: 804x1348
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_type: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_username: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_password: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_hostname: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_port: 80
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Network settings not set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - rdp_keyboard_remapping_list: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Log level set to to INFO
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_post_connect) - bpp: 32
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_post_connect) - CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpdr has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpsnd has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel cliprdr has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel drdynvc has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_connected) - [2023-01-28T12:43:51.348942+11] - yoda.lan - ewan - Connected to 10.1.2.2 via RDP
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - Connect signal emitted
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - We save the last successful connection date
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_state_last_success) - State file /home/ewan/.cache/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina.state.
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_state_last_success) - Last connection made on 20230128.
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - Saving credentials
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “password” saved for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina

(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_password” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “gateway_password” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_passphrase” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - Trying to present the window
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_on_focus_in) - Top level name is: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel Microsoft::Windows::RDS::DisplayControl has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_cliprdr_get_client_format_list) - gp=0x560008fd2640 sending to server the following local clipboard content formats
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_cliprdr_get_client_format_list) -      local clipboard format UTF8_STRING will be sent to remote as 13
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts from default: 20
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts from general preferences: 20
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts from general plugin: 0
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts set to: 20
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main_loop) - [2023-01-28T12:43:51.991448+11] - yoda.lan - ewan - Disconnected from 10.1.2.2 via RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpdr has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpsnd has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel cliprdr has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel Microsoft::Windows::RDS::DisplayControl has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel drdynvc has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main_loop) - RDP client disconnected
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnect signal received on RemminaProtocolWidget
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “password” saved for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina

(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_password” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “gateway_password” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_passphrase” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnected
```

And I tried again using SSH tunnel with TRACE log level;

```
This window can help you find connection problems.
You can stop and start the logging at any moment using the On/Off switch.
The stats button (Ctrl+T), can be useful to gather system info you may share when reporting a bug.
There is more info about debugging Remmina on https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/wikis/Usage/Remmina-debugging
(DEBUG) - (rcw_map_event) - Mapping: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_map_event) - Calling plugin mapping function
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Opening connection
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Disable smooth scrolling is set to 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Adding GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Have SSH
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - RDP data path is /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Not using system proxy settings
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel init
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - SSH tunnel initialization…
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port (tunnel)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - server: 10.1.2.2, port: 3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - We are initializing an SSH tunnel session
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - server:port = 10.1.2.2, server = 10.1.2.2, port = 22
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - Initialized SSH struct from file with ssh->server = 10.1.2.2 and SSH->port = 22
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->user: ewan
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->password: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->auth: 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->charset: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->kex_algorithms: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->ciphers: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->hostkeytypes: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->proxycommand: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->stricthostkeycheck: 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->compression: no
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_from_file) - ssh->privkeyfile: /home/ewan/.ssh/id_rsa
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_init_tunnel) - Creating SSH tunnel to “10.1.2.2” via SSH…
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - server=10.1.2.2 port=22 is_tunnel=Yes tunnel_entrance_host=(null) tunnel_entrance_port=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - Setting SSH_OPTIONS_HOST to 10.1.2.2 and SSH_OPTIONS_PORT to 22
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_IDENTITY is now /home/ewan/.ssh/id_rsa
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_set_algo: Setting method: no allowed algorithm for method "server host key algo" (+ssh-rsa,ssh-dss)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - ssh_config have been correctly parsed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_USER is now ewan
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - Parsing ssh_config for SSH_OPTIONS_PROXYCOMMAND returned an error: Setting method: no allowed algorithm for method "server host key algo" (+ssh-rsa,ssh-dss)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_set: Invalid argument in ssh_options_set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_PROXYCOMMAND does not have a valid value. (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_get: Unknown ssh option 25
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - Parsing ssh_config for SSH_OPTIONS_HOSTKEYS returned an error: Unknown ssh option 25
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_set: Invalid argument in ssh_options_set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_HOSTKEYS does not have a valid value. (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_get: Unknown ssh option 24
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - Parsing ssh_config for SSH_OPTIONS_KEY_EXCHANGE returned an error: Unknown ssh option 24
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_set: Invalid argument in ssh_options_set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_KEY_EXCHANGE does not have a valid value. (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_get: Unknown ssh option 15
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - Parsing ssh_config for SSH_OPTIONS_CIPHERS_C_S returned an error: Unknown ssh option 15
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_set: Invalid argument in ssh_options_set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_CIPHERS_C_S does not have a valid value. (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_get: Unknown ssh option 21
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - Parsing ssh_config for SSH_OPTIONS_STRICTHOSTKEYCHECK returned an error: Unknown ssh option 21
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_STRICTHOSTKEYCHECK is now 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_options_get: Unknown ssh option 22
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - Parsing ssh_config for SSH_OPTIONS_COMPRESSION returned an error: Unknown ssh option 22
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - SSH_OPTIONS_COMPRESSION is now no
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - socket_callback_connected: Socket connection callback: 1 (0)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_known_hosts_read_entries: Failed to open the known_hosts file '/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts': No such file or directory
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - TCP KeepAlive enabled
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - TCP_KEEPIDLE set to 20
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - TCP_KEEPCNT set to 3
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - TCP_KEEPINTVL set to 10
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_init_session) - TCP_USER_TIMEOUT set to 60000
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_packet_userauth_failure: Access denied for 'none'. Authentication that can continue: publickey,password
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_log_callback) - ssh_key_cmp: key types don't match!
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth) - Methods supported by server: SSH_AUTH_METHOD_PASSWORD SSH_AUTH_METHOD_PUBLICKEY 
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth) - SSH_AUTH_PASSWORD (0)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth) - SSH using remmina_ssh_auth_password
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth_password) - Password authentication
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth_password) - Authentication with SSH password returned: 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth_password) - Authenticated with SSH password. (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth_gui) - Returned 1 at 1st attempt with the following message:
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_auth_gui) - Could not authenticate with SSH password. 
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_init_tunnel) - Tunnel auth returned 1
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_init_tunnel) - Authentication success
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Starting tunnel to: (null), port: 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - protocol_plugin_start_direct_tunnel() returned 127.0.0.1:4732
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel has been optionally initialized. Now connecting to 127.0.0.1:4732
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - gfx_h264_available: 1
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set by the user: 804x1348
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set after workarounds: 804x1348
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_type: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_username: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_password: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_hostname: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_port: 80
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Network settings not set
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - rdp_keyboard_remapping_list: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Log level set to to TRACE
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_tunnel_create_forward_channel) - SSH tunnel destination is 10.1.2.2
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_post_connect) - bpp: 32
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_post_connect) - CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpdr has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpsnd has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel drdynvc has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_connected) - [2023-01-28T12:55:25.337789+11] - yoda.lan - ewan - Connected to 127.0.0.1 via RDP
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - Connect signal emitted
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - We save the last successful connection date
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_state_last_success) - State file /home/ewan/.cache/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina.state.
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_state_last_success) - Last connection made on 20230128.
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - Saving credentials
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “password” saved for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina

(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “ssh_tunnel_password” saved for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina

(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “gateway_password” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_passphrase” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_connect) - Trying to present the window
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelConnectedEventHandler) - Channel Microsoft::Windows::RDS::DisplayControl has been opened
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_on_focus_in) - Top level name is: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts from default: 20
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts from general preferences: 20
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts from general plugin: 0
(DEBUG) - (rf_auto_reconnect) - maxattempts set to: 20
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main_loop) - [2023-01-28T12:55:26.027296+11] - yoda.lan - ewan - Disconnected from 127.0.0.1 via RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_tunnel_main_thread_proc) - tunnel disconnected because Could not read from tunnel listening socket. 
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpdr has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel rdpsnd has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel Microsoft::Windows::RDS::DisplayControl has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_tunnel_destroy) - [Tunnel with idx 0 has been disconnected
(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_tunnel_free) - tunnel->thread = 0

(DEBUG) - (remmina_ssh_free) - Disconnecting SSH session
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_OnChannelDisconnectedEventHandler) - Channel drdynvc has been closed
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main_loop) - RDP client disconnected
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnect signal received on RemminaProtocolWidget
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “password” saved for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina

(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_store_password) - Password “ssh_tunnel_password” saved for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina

(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “gateway_password” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - We have a secret and disablepasswordstoring=0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_plugin_glibsecret_delete_password) - password “ssh_tunnel_passphrase” deleted for file /home/ewan/.local/share/remmina/group_rdp_quick-connect_10-1-2-2.remmina
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnected
```

I have also tried connecting from my laptop (Garuda Linux) using Remmina with the same result.

Any help or ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So I have fixed the issue... At least for now.

I remembered that I was trying to set up RDP as a service on my Ubuntu box by manually installing and setting up xrdp in terminal. Even with this service not running, it appeared to conflict with the inbuilt RDP setting within Gnome, and removing the xrdp package and restarting appeared to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Flatpak Remmina crashed on me and then would not connect to anything.
Enable Debugging from the hamburger menu and look at about the last line.

**G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL**

```
> flatpak ps  #find the instance id of flatpak process for remmina.
> flatpak ps | egrep -i remmina
> flatpak kill $(flatpak ps | egrep -i remmina | cut -f1)
> flatpak run org.remmina.Remmina $@ &
> # remmina works now :)  :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem is related to mine: my Remmina client (on Ubuntu 22.04) would crash immediately upon connecting to "Screen Sharing" (on Ubuntu 22.04), where RDP is now the default screen sharing protocol.

This happened only after a valid password was provided.

My fix: change both client and screen-share host's "display server" from Wayland to Xorg... see this:

[How to switch from the Wayland display server to Xorg X11 on Ubuntu 22.04](https://helpdesk.psionline.com/hc/en-gb/articles/13470827149332-How-to-perform-the-switch-from-the-Wayland-display-server-to-Xorg-X11-on-Linux-Ubuntu-22-04-LTS)

Bonus: this also fixed my broken drag-and-drop problems which I experienced when trying to drag a file out of a zip file with the Archive Manager.